# Can this hacky enum be improved?

Tags: java, coding-style

For a benchmark, I need three different settings ("keep all", "keep size", and "keep nothing"), so I though I could use an enum. Then I saw that I need to run some of the cases multiple times (the benchmark uses a seeded Random) and my original enum got pretty inflexible. For [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper), I need to repeat the enum items. After some failed tries to make it properly, I ended up with this hacky idea:

```
private enum Randomization {
    USE_EXAMPLE_1,
    USE_EXAMPLE_2,
    KEEP_EXAMPLE_SIZE_1,
    RANDOM_1,
    RANDOM_2,
    RANDOM_3,
    ;

    final boolean keepAll;
    final boolean keepSize;

    private Randomization() {
        keepAll = name().startsWith("U");
        keepSize = !name().startsWith("R");
    }
}
```

It does exactly what I want, I can add or remove experiments with minimum overhead. Is there any nicer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any nicer solution?

Well, it's not really very clear why you need these repeated enum values in the first place - I suspect I'd have an enum which *just* included the logical values, and then populate a collection using repeated values instead.

Another option would be to have an enum like the current one, *and* a more logical enum, where the constructor to the "repetitive" enum takes a reference to an instance of the "logical" one instead.

If you really, really want to keep the current structure, I'd personally ditch the inference of the `keepSize` and `keepAll` parts, and use a parameterized constructor instead:

```
private enum Randomization {
    USE_EXAMPLE_1(true, true),
    USE_EXAMPLE_2(true, true),
    KEEP_EXAMPLE_SIZE_1(false, true),
    RANDOM_1(false, false),
    RANDOM_2(false, false),
    RANDOM_3(false, false),
    ;

    final boolean keepAll;
    final boolean keepSize;

    private Randomization(boolean keepAll, boolean keepSize) {
        this.keepAll = keepAll;
        this.keepSize = keepSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: *populate a collection* - Normally yes, but how could I make Caliper to work with it? I can write `@Param Randomization randomization` and it tries all values. This works also for `boolean`s, but for anything else you need to enumerate (as string arguments to the annotation) the values to be used.

Comment: @maaartinus: I haven't used Caliper, but I'd be quite surprised if this was *really* the best way of doing it.

Comment: It would be a bad idea if I needed let's say five or more repetitions. But I only wanted to try multiple seeds for the randomized experiments and a single trial for the deterministic ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can have fields in your enum and do something like the following. Instance methods of the enum can access the fields like in usual classes:

```
private enum Randomization {
    USE_EXAMPLE_1(1),
    USE_EXAMPLE_2(2),
    // ...

    private final int flag;

    Randomization(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

This avoids the problem of potential refactorings renaming the values of the `enum` and doesn't tie you to the name.